# Problem with project dependency tree in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dependencies

I've cloned a GitHub repo and was installing the packages. I first ran `yarn install`, and then I ran `yarn build`. But the second command gave me an error:

[image: Error Image]

Could somebody help me with this please? I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: have you tried the 4 steps as recommended?

Comment: Hi @keikai, yes I did. And then I ran `npm install` again, and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it was because I had installed webpack in previous directories. You have probably installed a webpack in `C:\Users\eden1\node_modules`. Try removing that with `npm remove webpack` when you are located in `C:\Users\eden1` or remove the globally installed webpack with `npm remove -g webpack`.